# Jones–Sato–Wada–Wiens diophantine equation

Tags: prime-numbers, computability-theory, diophantine-equations

I came across this from the 1993 book [Matiyasevic - Hilbert's 10th problem](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hilbert_s_Tenth_Problem/42h5VRwG5rcC). Typeset from another question:
\begin{align}
P(a,b,\dotsc,z)=(k+2)\Bigl(1&-(wz+h+j-q)^2\\ 
       &-\left[(gk+2g+k+1)(h+j)+h-z\right]^2\\  
       &-[2n+p+q+z-e]^2\\ 
       &-\left[16(k+1)^{3}(k+2)(n+1)^2+1-f^2\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[e^{3}(e+2)(a+1)^2+1-o^2\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[(a^2-1)y^2+1-x^2\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[16r^2y^{4}\left(a^2-1\right)+1-u^2\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[\left(\left(a+u^2\left(u^2-a\right)\right)^2-1\right)(n+4dy)^2+1-(x+cu)^2\right]^2\\  
       &-\left[n+l+v-y\right]^2-\left[\left(a^2-1\right)l^2+1-m^2\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[ai+k+1-l-i\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[p+l(a-n-1)+b\left(2an+2a-n^2-2n-2\right)-m\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[q+y(a-p-1)+s\left(2ap+2a-p^2-2p-2\right)-x\right]^2\\ 
       &-\left[z+pl(a-p)+t\left(2ap-p^2-1\right)-pm\right]^2\Bigr).
\end{align}
This polynomial's set of positive values is exactly the set of prime numbers.
My question is, isn't it always divisible by the $(k+2)$ term? I noticed this experimentally first before looking closer and seeing it should have been obvious.

To rephrase, suppose to the contrary there was an assignment $a,b,\dotsc,z$ such that $P(a,b,\dotsc,z) = p_i$ for some prime $p_i$. Then $p_i = (k+2)(1 - \dotsb) \implies (k+2) \mid p_i$, a contradiction.

The [next page](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hilbert_s_Tenth_Problem/42h5VRwG5rcC?gbpv=1&pg=PA56) of the book contains the following observation:

> This polynomial contains 26 variables (all the letters of the alphabet!), and the set of its *positive* values is exactly the set of all prime numbers.  Considering only positive values, one can use, instead of (1.4.8), a representation of the form
> $$x_0\bigl(1 - D^2(x_0, \dotsc, x_m)\bigr) = a.$$
> This minor modification leads to the following paradox:  the polynomial written above, representing only primes, is itself the product of two polynomials!

What am I missing?

Comment: In order to get a contradiction you need to show that there is a positive value of this polynomial with $k+2\ne1$.

Comment: $k + 2 \mid p_i$ is not a contradiction if $\lvert k + 2\rvert = p_i$ or $\lvert k + 2\rvert = 1$.  I suppose the polynomial value is only positive in these cases.  (You also may want to avoid using $p$ for a prime value when it is one of the variables in the polynomial.)

Comment: The polynomial comes from [Jones and Sato and Wada and Wiens - Diophantine representation of the set of prime numbers](https://doi.org/10.2307/2318339).

Comment: @LSpice the setting of the book deals only with non-negative integers because it demonstrates the decision problem is equivalent to arbitrary integers. Because of this I assumed $k+2 \geq 2$. The paper elaborates on the k+2 term being prime, I will take a look, thanks.

Comment: Also thank you for the extensive edits to my post.